# Extra Simulators On Xcode 7.1

Tags: xcode, ios-simulator

I’m having the simulators on my Xcode as shown in the screenshot. I have no idea what’s the purpose of these extra simulators. Does anyone have any idea and any way to remove them?
[image]

Answer (score 1):

The extra simulators have no "purpose"; they are left over from earlier Xcode upgrades.

Comment: Okay Thanks. Anyway to remove them.

Comment: Absolutely, but that is not the question you asked, is it?